# Qt Quick Controls 2.0 circular spinbox

Tags: qtquickcontrols2

In Qt, it is possible to create [circular spinboxes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#wrapping-prop)?

Is such a feature available for Qt Quick Controls 2.0?

Has someone an idea how to achieve that by [customizing the spinbox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-spinbox)?

Comment: Please send a suggestion at bugreports.qt.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SpinBox::wrap](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#wrap-prop) has been introduced in QtQuick.Controls 2.3 (Qt 5.10).

> This property holds whether the spinbox wraps. The default value is `false`.
>
> If wrap is `true`, stepping past `to` changes the value to `from` and vice versa.